# Can I have a planet with 150 kph winds across the entire surface?

Tags: wind

Is it possible for the average wind speed to be high enough that even the "calm" areas have 150 kph winds, while still maintaining an atmosphere and breathable air?

I'm not talking about sandstorms or hurricanes; just the normal wind speed at ground level being like how it is in the stratosphere.

Comment: It's easy to say "yes." For example, [scientists measured nearly 1500kph winds near Jupiter's poles](https://scitechdaily.com/incredibly-powerful-900-mph-winds-in-jupiters-atmosphere-measured-for-the-first-time/), and the closer you get to the poles, the less violent the air (the poles are your problem, btw). However, can *your* planet have 150kph winds? You've told us nothing about your planet, so the answer must necessarily be "maybe, if your planet can support it." Earth can hit those speeds (and better) with tornadoes, but not sustained wind over even the majority of the surface.

Comment: Venus has 100 m/s or 360 km/h winds.  The crux of your question is "breathable" right ?

Answer (score 26):

Across the *entire* surface?  No.  One of the consequences of the [hairy ball theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hairy_ball_theorem) is that any atmospheric flow pattern has at least one calm spot, at the center of a cyclone.

Across *most* of the surface?  Sure, you just need an energy source, an energy sink, and a lack of obstructions.  A tidally-locked planet should work just fine.

Comment: The hairy ball theorem specifies "even-dimensional n-spheres" but a planet isn't an "even dimensional n-sphere" because the atmosphere has thickness too. For example, high altitude winds can point in a different direction to winds at a lower altitude. Additionally, while the theorem indicates that there will be a calm spot in a static-field case, I think this calm spot could move across the sphere with respect to time, so while you might be able to chase the calm spot(s) with a fast aircraft or similar, from a ground-based perspective you'd still basically always have some sort of wind.

Comment: @Dragongeek The surface of the planet IS an even dimensional sphere, and assuming the wind differs continuously across the surface the hairy ball theorem applies and you necessarily have at least some calm spot. If you try to move the calm spot so that a person staying in that spot still experiences wind, are you sure you don't just get a new resulting wind vector field that still must possess a calm spot?

Comment: Of course, the calm spots can move over time, so that no calm spot stays calm for long.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: Even so, the calm spot must move along a continuous path over the surface - it can't "jump around" (but it could move very quickly). However, a fast-moving calm spot will be difficult to justify in terms of plausible weather phenomena. Cyclones and anticyclones typically move at a relatively sedate pace.

Comment: What if the planet is donut shaped... wait hear me out, it could be mostly spherical but with a cave that connects two points on the surface, making the planet topologically a donut. You can comb the hair on a donut just fine. Instead of a calm spot you have a "wind goes down and through the cave" spot. Or the same effect could be achieved with an open arch on the surface.

Answer (score 3):

Only if the atmosphere is cold or thick, and the ground is smooth.

If you [look at the planets of our solar system](https://spaceaustralia.com.au/blogs/news/what-is-the-wind-speed-on-other-planets-in-the-solar-system-%F0%9F%8C%AC%EF%B8%8F), where are the highest winds?  Not on Earth.  Venus has high winds because its atmosphere is thicker... but the wind speed near ground level is low, according to the probes sent there.

Mars' winds are higher, even though the atmosphere is thinner.  Why?  It's colder.  Winds are higher on Jupiter, and higher still on Saturn, high on Uranus and really high on Neptune.  This seems to suggest that to have high winds, you need thick atmospheres and low turbulence, since heat causes convection and turbulence.

However, that article also suggests that [HD 189733b](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HD_189733_b), a hot jupiter-sized planet, has wind speeds in the range of 8700kph/5400mph.  That would appear to have something to do with the planet's thick atmosphere, though it might also be rotating rapidly, carrying the atmosphere along with the rapidly spinning core.  At a distance of 65 lightyears, scientists would be tracking changes in albedo rather than finer surface patterns.

So, to have high winds, you need lots of gas and low drag conditions.  A rough, rocky surface would slow the winds down.

Answer (score 3):

**ASSUMPTION:** Your question relates to an Earth 'like' world with a similar atmospheric pressure/composition and a similar landmass to ocean ratio.

**ANSWER:** Sure, if the planet is either tidally locked to its primary so that one side permanently faces its sun and the other side faces away. The extreme difference in thermal equilibrium between the two sides (one very hot, one very cold) would tend to generate very high winds as physics tried to redistribute heat more evenly  around the planet.

Failing that a *very slow rotation* should achieve the same effect.  Take a planet like Earth and simply increase the length of its day/night cycle so that you get much longer and therefore (on average) hotter days and equally long/colder nights. Global wind speeds should speed up accordingly.

(Maybe there's someone on this forum with access to climate modelling software that could give you a ball park estimate for how long the Earth's day would have to be to reach your desired average wind speeds.)